# How to generate UML class model from a Relational Model?

Tags: uml, relational-database

Does anyone know if it's possible to generate a UML Class Model from a Database Relational Model? How?

edit:

To clarify what I consider to be a UML Class Model (UCM) and a Database Relational Model (DRM).

The UCM is a higher abstraction than DRM. On the UCM we don't talk about table but rather about entities. In UCM we model the properties of an entities and the relationships with which other.

In the DRM it is the opposite, we don't talk about entities, we talk about tables. Typically, if not every time, the DRM will have more tables than the number of entities in the UML.

I hope I have made myself clear now.

P.S: I am using [SparxSystems Enterprise Arquitecht](http://www.sparxsystems.com/products/ea/index.html).

Thanks.

Comment: A relational diagram has the exact content of a UML diagram with different notation.  What part of the notation change confuses you?  Please provide examples of what you think is a "relational model" and what you think of as a "UML Class Diagram".  Is some part of the boxes and lines part  confusing you?  If so, what part?  There are only three things depicted (entities, associations and constraints) so you need to explain what part of these things confuse you.

Comment: what modeling tool are you using?

Comment: @Silx: I am using Enterprise Architect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A database relational model in [Enterprise Architect][1] is just a stereotyped Class diagram where the Class elements are tables and the attributes are the columns.

So to answer your question, Yes it is possible to generate the relational model into a class model simply by using the Model Driven Architecture (MDA) transforms of Enterprise Architect to transform it directly to a class model.

To do this:

In the Project Browser of Enterprise Architect right on the DRM package then select Transform current package (Crtl+Shift+H)

Select an appropriate language.

Click "Do Transform" - and follow the promps to save the new class elements in the project browser.

Once this is done you can tweek exactly how you want the UCM to look (more/less entities etc). Hopefully this will get you 99% of the way there.

Comment: The problem is about "Select an appropriate language" : wich one ? I do not seen any target langage to transform Database model ( CLass with stereotype "table") into a UML Class model.

Comment: Try generate to "DDL" then select the target database language on the package/elements once its done.